# Is there an R Process to transform multiple rows to one row

Tags: pivot-table

I have a set of policy numbers with associated convictions on separate rows (if more than 1 conviction) and would like to transform to 1 row with multiple convictions.

Dummy data below:
[Current Data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/E6hJ7.png)

And would like to transform to the below:
[Transformed Data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nv6wX.png)

Please can someone help.

Comment: Welcome. Please read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) post on how to make a good example. In particular, please never share data as images, always as formatted plain text (using ``dput()``. It makes it much easier others to help you. Thanks.

Comment: Thanks for the advice.  Didn't realise it would come across as an image.

Comment: will try again with the data  From this Policy Number Code Date
POLNUM000003 AB30 25/11/2020
POLNUM000031 CD30 28/06/2018
POLNUM000035 ED40 22/07/2017
POLNUM000042 AB30 18/01/2021
POLNUM000042 CA90 17/01/2021
POLNUM000042 BC30 16/11/2020
POLNUM000051 EF50 10/11/2020

Comment: To--> Policy Number Code Date
POLNUM000003 AB30 25/11/2020
POLNUM000031 CD30 28/06/2018
POLNUM000035 ED40 22/07/2017
POLNUM000042 AB30 18/01/2021
POLNUM000042 CA90 17/01/2021
POLNUM000042 BC30 16/11/2020
POLNUM000051 EF50 10/11/2020

Comment: A colleague has helped me out with this